# The sum $\sum_{r=1}^{p-1} r(r|p)$ when $p$ is an odd prime of the form $4k+3$, $k\geq 1$.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

In the book Apostol Analytic Number Theory, $(r|p)$ denotes the Legendre Symbol. The exercise tell us to prove when $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, $$\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}r(r|p)=0.$$
I can solve this quickly, but I wonder what if $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$? Either this book or the number theory textbook by Rosen both didn't include this question. This question should be easily thought but not easily calculated. For prime $p$ of the form $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$, I let $$f(p)=\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}r(r|p)$$
and I get these values: 
\begin{align*}
f(7)&=-7\\
f(11)&=-11\\
f(19)&=-19\\
f(23)&=-3(23)\\
f(31)&=-3(31)\\
f(43)&=-43\\
f(47)&=-5(47)\\
f(59)&=-3(59)\\
f(67)&=-67\\
f(71)&=-7(71)\\
f(79)&=-5(79)\\
f(83)&=-3(83)\\
f(103)&=-5(103)\\
f(107)&=-3(107)\\
f(127)&=-5(127)\\
f(131)&=-5(131)\\
f(139)&=-3(139)\\
f(151)&=-7(151)\\
f(163)&=-163\\
f(167)&=-11(167)
\end{align*}

How can I observe the pattern?

Comment: It seems that $f(p)=-p\cdot h(-p)$ where $h(d)$ denotes the [class number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html) of the quadratic field with fundamental discriminant $d$. This suggests the problem is hard.

Comment: @Servaes After I check the table, it does really hold! Thanks for your information, I think I better not continue doing the research on this......

Comment: There is a proof by means of the Dirichlet class number formula, involving $L$-functions, so perhaps by the end of chapter 12 of Apostol a proof will be within your reach.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look of that.